# Access specific information within worklogs in jira-python

Tags: python, jira, python-jira

How can I get the minutes spent from a worklog from an issue using the jira-python library?

Using the jirashell I see that the issue has the attribute issue.fields.worklog, however when I try to access that in my python code I get the error: `AttributeError: type object 'PropertyHolder' has no attribute 'worklog'`.

If I create a jira client and do jira_client.worklogs(ticket.key) in my python code, it returns a list of Worklogs and their ids but I don't know what to do with that. I see in the documentation there's a worklog() function that takes in the issue id, and the worklog id, but I don't understand what it returns and how I would use that/if it is what I'm looking for.

Comment: It seems that jira python module doesn't provide this capability so far. However, this is the closest answer I could find so far: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12776109/work-logs-for-a-period-from-jira-rest-api

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a roundabout way of doing it through the client.

As I iterate through each issue I get the list of worklogs per ticket by doing `worklogs = jira_client.worklogs(issue.key)` and then i iterate through all of the worklog items in the worklogs list (a nested for loop):

```
for worklog in worklogs:
    totaltime += readtime(worklog.timeSpent)
```

Using the jirashell I accessed a specific worklog of a specific ticket: `wl = jira_client.worklog(<issue key>, <worklog id>)` then I typed in `wl.`  and pressed TAB, it listed the following:

> wl.author, wl.comment, wl.created, wl.delete, wl.find, wl.id, wl.raw, wl.self, wl.started,
>   wl.timeSpent, wl.timeSpentSeconds, wl.update, wl.updateAuthor, wl.updated

(**Note**: you need to include the period at the end of wl before pressing tab)

Running `wl.timespent` in the jirashell gave me gave me a unicode string with the number and then h or m for hour or minute (for example: `u'6h'`). Then I new that once I generated the worklog object in my loop above, I could access the time by using the timepsent attribute.

(**Note**: My `readtime` function turns the string into an integer and converts hours to minutes, and is not shown here)

The jirashell really helps with trying to find the attributes of the fields, etc. (**Note**: you need to install jira-python in addition to jira in order to run jirashell. Also if you installed jira-python in your virtualenv you need to run `env/bin/jirashell` from your command line once you are in your project's directory.)