# Unable to access jira worklogs via python-jira

Tags: python, jira

I am trying to access the worklogs in python by using the [jira python library](http://jira.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples.html). I am doing the following:

```
issues = jira.search_issues("key=MYTICKET-1")
print(issues[0].fields.worklogs)

issue = jira.search_issues("MYTICKET-1")
print(issue.fields.worklogs)
```

as described in the documentation, chapter 2.1.4. However, I get the following error (for both cases):

```
AttributeError: type object 'PropertyHolder' has no attribute 'worklogs'
```

Is there something I am doing wrong? Is the documentation outdated? How to access worklogs (or other fields, like comments etc)? And what is a `PropertyHolder`? How to access it (its not described in the documentation!)?

Answer (score 8):

This is because **it seems** `jira.JIRA.search_issues` doesn't fetch all "builtin" fields, like `worklog`, by default (although documentation only uses vague term ["fields - [...] Default is to include *all fields*"](https://jira.readthedocs.io/en/master/api.html?highlight=worklogs#jira.JIRA.search_issues) 
 - "all" out of what?).

You either have to use [`jira.JIRA.issue`](https://jira.readthedocs.io/en/master/api.html?highlight=worklogs#jira.JIRA.issue):

```py
client = jira.JIRA(...)
issue = client.issue("MYTICKET-1")
```

or explicitly list fields which you want to fetch in `jira.JIRA.search_issues`:

```py
client = jira.JIRA(...)
issue = client.search_issues("key=MYTICKET-1", fields=[..., 'worklog'])[0]
```

Also be aware that this way you will get at most 20 worklog items attached to your JIRA issue instance. If you need all of them you should use [`jira.JIRA.worklogs`](https://jira.readthedocs.io/en/master/api.html?highlight=worklogs#jira.JIRA.worklogs):

```py
client = jira.JIRA(...)
issue = client.issue("MYTICKET-1")
worklog = issue.fields.worklog
all_worklogs = client.worklogs(issue) if worklog.total > 20 else worklog.worklogs
```

Answer (score 0):

This question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24375473/access-specific-information-within-worklogs-in-jira-python) is similar to yours and someone has posted a work around.

There is a also a [similar question on Github](https://github.com/pycontribs/jira/issues/224) in relation to attachments (not worklogs).  The last answer in the comments has workaround that might assist.

Comment: Please include a more meaningful answer instead of simply linking to answers, as the links may become stale or removed over time. If this question is a duplicate, you can add a comment suggesting it be marked as such.